# How to include libsodium.dll on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, wcf, unmanaged, libsodium

I am writing a WCF IIS hosted service and trying to use libsodium. It works fine on my PC which runs Windows 7, but it sulks about not being able to find the libsodium.dll on Windows Server 2012. It continues sulking even if I stick the DLL into the Windows directory.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried to add it to the "bin" folder?

Comment: Yes. And I've added it to the path variable. The same code works fine on my own developer machine.

Comment: The other solution I guess would be to use https://github.com/mheyman/Isopoh.Cryptography.Argon2 instead.